# rx java run observables on multiple different threads

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java

I'm new to rx java, so I'm probably missing something very basic.  In the code sample below, what I'd *like* to happen is:

1. SampleController receives request on http-nio thread
2. CompositeService processing runs on a new thread A and releases the nio request thread.
3. CompositeService calls HelloService which makes a network call on thread B.
4. CompositeService calls WorldService which makes a network call on thread C.

3 and 4 run concurrently, and when the results are ready, we use the results to make a network call on thread A.

Instead what I'm seeing is that 3 and 4 execute sequentially on the http-nio thread, and only the CompositeService executes on a new thread.  It appears that my subscribeOn calls in 3 and 4 are not having any effect.  How do I get 3 and 4 to run concurrently?

**SampleController**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rx-java-sample")
public class SampleController {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CompositeService compositeService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public DeferredResult<String> getCompositeString() 
                    throws ApiGatewayException, ApiValidationException {
        log.info("Received getCompositeObject request");

        Observable<String> compositeObject = compositeService.getCompositeString();

        return toDeferredResult(compositeObject);
    }

    private DeferredResult<String> toDeferredResult(Observable<String> compositeObject) {
        DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<String>();

        compositeObject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                result.setErrorResult(throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String compositeString) {
                log.info("Returning compositeObject: " + compositeString);
                result.setResult(compositeString);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

**HelloService**:

```
@Service
public class HelloService {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    public Observable<String> getHello() {
        log.trace("calling get hello");
        return Observable.just(makeNetworkCall());
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall() {
        log.trace("making hello network call");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**WorldService**:

```
@Service
public class WorldService {

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    public Observable<String> getWorld() {
        log.trace("calling get world");
        return Observable.just(makeNetworkCall());
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall() {
        log.trace("making world network call");
        return "world";
    }
}
```

**CompositeService**:

```
@Service
public class CompositeService {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompositeService.class);

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @Autowired
    private WorldService worldService;

    public Observable<String> getCompositeString() {
        log.trace("Calling getCompositeObject");

        Observable<String> foo = helloService.getHello().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<String> bar = worldService.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

        return Observable.zip(foo, bar, (f, b) -> makeNetworkCall(f,b));
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall(String hello, String world) {
        log.trace("making composite network call");
        return hello + " " +  world;
    }
}
```

**log**:

```
2016-06-16 07:10:13 INFO [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [SampleController.java:32] Received getCompositeObject request
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [CompositeService.java:23] Calling getCompositeObject
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [HelloService.java:15] calling get hello
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [HelloService.java:20] making hello network call
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [WorldService.java:15] calling get world
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [http-nio-9050-exec-1] [WorldService.java:20] making world network call
2016-06-16 07:10:13 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-3] [CompositeService.java:32] making composite network call
2016-06-16 07:10:13 INFO [RxNewThreadScheduler-3] [SampleController.java:54] Returning compositeObject: hello world
```

Comment: fyi, there is Schedulers.computation() for cpu bound work and Schedulers.io() for io bound - often better candidates than Schedulers.newThread().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Observable::defer` for these cases:

```
  public Observable<String> getWorld() {
      log.trace("calling get world");

      return Observable.defer(() -> makeNetworkCall());
  }
```

This ensures that your code gets called *each* time that the observable gets subsribed on.

Also, I'd suggest using `Schedulers.io()`; it's a configurable thread pool that by default expands as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was my use of Observable.just rather than Observable.fromCallable.  Modifying the service code from above as below produced the behavior I was looking for.  I am still looking for feedback on if this is the "recommended" way to do this.  In particular I'm not sure if the use of toBlocking() in CompositeService is correct.  I will likely use this pattern extensively in my code and I'd like to get it right.

**HelloService**:

```
@Service
public class HelloService {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    public Observable<String> getHello() {
        log.trace("calling get hello");

        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> { 
            return makeNetworkCall();
        });
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall() {
        log.trace("making hello network call");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**WorldService**:

```
@Service
public class WorldService {

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    public Observable<String> getWorld() {
        log.trace("calling get world");

        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> { 
            return makeNetworkCall();
        });
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall() {
        log.trace("making world network call");
        return "world";
    }
}
```

`CompositeService`:

```
@Service
public class CompositeService {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompositeService.class);

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @Autowired
    private WorldService worldService;

    public Observable<String> getCompositeString() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> { 
            return getCompositeStringImpl().toBlocking().single();
        });
    }

    public Observable<String> getCompositeStringImpl() {
        log.trace("Calling getCompositeObject");

        Observable<String> foo = helloService.getHello().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<String> bar = worldService.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

        return Observable.zip(foo, bar, (f, b) -> makeNetworkCall(f, b));
    }

    private String makeNetworkCall(String hello, String world) {
        log.trace("making composite network call");
        return hello + " " + world;
    }
}
```

**logs**:

```
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-1] [CompositeService.java:29] Calling getCompositeObject
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-1] [HelloService.java:15] calling get hello
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-1] [WorldService.java:15] calling get world
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-2] [HelloService.java:23] making hello network call
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-3] [WorldService.java:23] making world network call
2016-06-16 08:15:50 TRACE [RxNewThreadScheduler-3] [CompositeService.java:38] making composite network call
2016-06-16 08:15:50 INFO [RxNewThreadScheduler-1] [SampleController.java:54] Returning compositeObject: hello world
```